# Reporting a serial downvoting!

Tags: discussion

There are clear serial downvotes against all my questions and answers. I have find out it times and times but I tried to ignore it and consider it as a right of reader to decide upvote or downvote a question or answer but now it is a different situation:

You see after being about 3 months here, one or more users are going to your profile and finding all your questions and answers and because they do not like one of your questions or answers or your personality, they commit to downvote all your questions and answers from 3 months ago to now!

Please check it as it has happened for me several times:

-4  today

-2  23 mins ago     downvote    What does “ Rape someone's mind” mean?

-2  24 mins ago     downvote    Is it acceptable to use “womyn” or “womin” instead of “women”?

2   yesterday

+2  09:03   accept  Who is whose sister or brother?

-1  2 days ago

+5 / -4     21:37   3 events     Who is whose sister or brother?

-1  21:52   downvoted   Who is whose sister or brother?

-1  16:30   downvoted   Who is whose sister or brother?

Comment: You aren’t going to be able to make much of a case about some sort of injustice about having received just two downvotes to two different questions close to each other like that. However, why don’t you explain to us why you yourself downvoted both those answers to the sister/brother question?  Wasn’t that unjust of you?

Comment: You are probably receiving downvotes ***because people do not like what you post.***  There is nothing wrong with that, any more than there is anything wrong with you yourself downvoting postings that you yourself do not like. My point in drawing attention to the way you outed yourself as a downvoter is that ***sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander.*** There is no sexist conspiracy here to flail against. If you learn to post things that garner upvotes and unlearn to post things that garner downvotes, you will be happier.

Answer (score 16):

> You see after being about 3 months here, one or more users are going to your profile and finding all your questions and answers and because they do not like one of your questions or answers or your personality, they commit to downvote all your questions and answers from 3 months ago to now!

In your time on the site, you've posted 11 answers and 9 questions. Of those, a total of 14 are not currently deleted and thus eligible to be voted on. No one person has voted for you even close to 14 times.

In the last month, no one has voted for you - up or down - more than twice.

Serial voting implies a series of votes from a single person, connected in some fashion by intent, time, type or all three. It is not generally possible for one person to vote "serially" for a single post - indeed, if you get multiple up-votes or down-votes for one post, it's a pretty good bet those are directly related to the content of the post and not directed at you personally.

Speaking as someone who has been the target of serial voters and who has spent a fair bit of my time while employed by Stack Exchange *investigating* serial voters, there is absolutely nothing in your record that would indicate anything of the sort... Except for a brief series of *up-votes* back in February (most of which were automatically invalidated by the system [that waiwai describes](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/reporting-a-serial-downvoting/3913#3913)).

If you ever have good reason to suspect that someone is specifically targeting you - by which I mean a *significant number of votes* on disparate posts written by you in a short period of time - then wait 24 hours; there's a good chance they'll go way. If they have not, flag a post for moderator attention and... Move on. This is not something worth worrying about.

Comment: Great answer. With the rider that This is **not** something **not** worth worrying about, for the mortals down here. :)

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. In general, serial downvoting is automatically reversed after 24 hours.
2. In this specific instance, the voting patterns I can see do not suggest that malicious serial downvoting (or upvoting) has taken place.

Comment: What worries me is that a negative indicator can be swiftly attached to (OK, in my estimation) a valid, accurate and useful answer.

Comment: @Edwin: A 'negative indicator' shows that somebody dislikes an answer you like. I don't myself find that either worrying or unusual.

Comment: Yes, but to a person looking for help, the obvious initial downvoting of a reasonable answer for personal reasons is hardly to be recommended. If downvotes had to be accompanied by a reason, and the downvoters were then themselves accountable, the situation would be improved.

Comment: @Edwin: Anyone who assumes that any downvote must be for personal reasons is not going to be open to reason in any event.